# Electric field and potential between two charges

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, homework-and-exercises

There are two point charges on the $x$ axis and $x'$ is a place where the potential, relative to infinity, is the biggest. Why is the electric field zero at this point?

Comment: The only point with a zero field in your charge distribution is the middle point between them, and at this point the potential is *minimum on the $x$ axis*, not maximum. So your statement is wrong.

Comment: Desperado, the strength of the electric field is proportional to the how quickly the electric potential changes with position (the slope of the potential).  So, for example, one can have a *constant* potential and zero electric field.  Now, at the top of a hill or the bottom of a valley, what is the slope?

Comment: I do not see how your statement is correct. The closer you get to any of the point particles the biggest the potential, and the strongest the electric field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement that $V$ is at an extremum can be written $\partial_i V=0$. Now think about the mathematical relation between $V$ and $E$ in electrostatics.